# JSP multiple consecutive selection

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Im learning JSP and i want to create simple online shop

1. Customer will select a brand

   - method connector.getBrands() will return list of availiable brands from a database
   - now the customer will see availiable options in another select
   - now i need to hold selected brand in a variable
2. Customer wil select a model

   - method connector.getModel(${brand}) will return list of availiable models
   - now the customer can select a model
   - now i need to hold selected brand and model
3. Customer will select a color

   - method connector.getColor(${brand}, ${model} will return list of availiable colors
   - now i need to hold all three values
4. Customer will click on "Continue" button to continue to another JSP page for order confirmation

Now, the problem is that whenever i click submit for "brand" or "model", the other selected field will reset(i tried setting a global variable from inside of "select" element but without any luck).

How can i modify this code so it will show apropriate brands, after selecting one, models from that brand and after that its availiable colors? (plus submitting all of these values to the next page)

Also it would be nice if a knew, how to access a value from "select" or "input" field without reloading a page

Here is my code for MotorbikeForm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<jsp:useBean id="connector" class="dealership.DatabaseConnector" scope="page"/>
<c:out value="${connector.initializeDatabase()}" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
<label>
Brand<br/>
<select name="brand" size="1">
<c:forEach var="element" items="${connector.getBrands()}">
<option><c:out value="${element}" /></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</label><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<!-- This line below is useless right now -->
<c:set var="brandVar" value="${brand}"/>
</form>

<form method="post">
<label>
Model<br/>
<select name="model" size="1">
<c:forEach var="element" items="${connector.getModels(param.brand)}">
<option><c:out value="${element}" /></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</label><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br/>
</form>

<form method="post">
<label>
Color<br/>
<select name="color" size="1">
<c:forEach var="element" items="${connector.getColors(param.brand, param.model)}">
<option><c:out value="${element}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
</label><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br/>
</form><br/><br/>

Next step<br/>
<form method="post" action="OrderConfirmation.jsp">
<input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't hit the database to get your *brands* and *models* every time the page reloads. You should fetch the values once and the save them in the `session` for reuse.

```
<c:if test="${empty brands}">
  <c:set var="brands" value="${connector.getBrands()}" scope="session" />
</c:if>
```

Second, you need to make sure that the `brand` gets reselected on subsequent page reloads.

```
<select name="brand" size="1">
  <c:forEach var="brand" items="${brands}">
    <option <c:out value="${brand == param.brand ? 'selected' : ''}" />>
      <c:out value="${brand}" />
    </option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Now, do the same for `model` but by also wrapping it in a `<c:if>` we avoid hitting the database on the first page load (because `brand` has not been selected yet) and optionally hide the blank drop-down as well.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.brand}">
  <c:if test="${empty param.model}">
    <c:set var="models" value="${connector.getModels(param.brand)}" scope="session" />
  </c:if>
  <form method="post">
    <label>Model<br/>
    <select name="model" size="1">
      <c:forEach var="model" items="${models}">
        <option <c:out value="${model == param.model ? 'selected' : ''}" />>
          <c:out value="${model}" />
        </option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
    </label><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="brand" value="${param.brand}"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br/>
  </form>
</c:if>
```

Repeating somewhat similar logic for `color` as well.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.model}">
  <c:if test="${empty param.color}">
    <c:set var="colors" value="${connector.getColors(param.brand, param.model)}"
           scope="session" />
  </c:if>
  <form method="post" action="OrderConfirmation.jsp">
    <label>Color<br/>
    <select name="color" size="1">
      <c:forEach var="color" items="${colors}">
        <option><c:out value="${color}"/></option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
    </label><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="brand" value="${param.brand}"/><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="model" value="${param.model}"/><br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Next step<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
  </form>
</c:if>
```

Notice, that your last `<form>` is unnecessary. Your `colors` form already has all the information (`brand`, `model`, and `color`) needed to place the order. Hence, I've directly set its `action` to *OrderConfirmation.jsp* instead.

Comment: @Peter Glad to help. You had put some efforts there.. screen shots with annotations. Had to answer :)